# Finding the segue being used

Tags: xcode, storyboard, segue

I am using a detail view controller which is linked from various segue.  I would like to perform an action in `viewDidLoad` depending on which controller is pushing the detail controller.

Is there a way I can figure out which segue is loading the detail controller?

Comment: What kind of code are you looking to run?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSStringFromClass](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSLocalizedString) if you set a delegate for the detail VC. An alternate way would be to set the ID in a `prepareForSegue:` method and either pass that to the detail VC or call a getter on the delegate.

```
NSString *class = [NSStringFromClass([self.delegate class]);
```

--

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
     if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"scrollerSegue"])
     {
         ScrollViewController * target = segue.destinationViewController;
         target.VC_Which_Pushed_ME = self.ID;

         // and/or
         target.delegate = self;
     }
}
```